# 4 posts per page from single category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, query-posts, get-posts

I've been trying to display posts that I've categorized as "news-categories". My goal is to only display 4 posts on sidebar of "cbs-news" slug underneath "news-categories" category.
By below mention code all the post underneath "cbs-news" are displaying. But i need to display only 4 latest post.

```
 <ul class="list4 martop5">
    <?php 
            $args = array('tax_query' => array( array('taxonomy' => 'news-categories', 'posts_per_page' => '5', 'field' => 'slug','terms' => 'cbs-news',
            'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )
            )));
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            if($the_query->have_posts() ) : 
            //have_posts("showposts=4");
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
            ?>
        <li>
           <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li><!-- /.service -->

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

        <p>Nothing Here.</p>

    <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write the wrong code

```
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('posts_per_page' => '5', 
              'paged' => $paged,
              'tax_query' => array( array('taxonomy' => 'news-categories',
                                          'field' => 'slug',
                                          'terms' => 'cbs-news')
                                  )
              );
```

You can also take help in [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Wow, Its working...Thanks for the help..:) Waise kithe de ho bhaji..:)

Comment: New Delhi de :D

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not correct, try this instead :

```
 $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 );

 $args = array(
 'tax_query' => array( 
                  array('taxonomy' => 'news-categories',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => 'cbs-news'
                      )
               ), 
 'posts_per_page' => '5',
 'paged' => $paged
 );
```